# Any improvement to my completed blackjack game in oop of python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented

I have learnt python 3 for about 1 month. After I learnt the basics of oop in python, I try to create a blackjack game based on tutorial's framework. I spent 1 weeks to complete it. I want to see whether some further improvements can be done on my code. Thank you!

My blackjack game steps:

1. dealer(one exposed card, one hidden card) and four players(two exposed cards) at the beginning
2. if dealer has the exposed card with Ace, ask whether the players want an insurance
3. (hit, stand, double down, surrender) available for normal hand, (split) added for special hand
4. dealer get cards until he reaches 17
5. showing result
6. ask for a new game

My tools:

- Anaconda (python 3.7)
- Pycharm 2019.3.3

```
# Main author: Yip
# Second author: 駱昊
import random
from functools import total_ordering


@total_ordering
class Card(object):
    """one single card"""

    def __init__(self, suite, face):
        self._suite = suite
        self._face = face

    @property
    def face(self):
        return self._face

    @property
    def suite(self):
        return self._suite

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.face == other

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.face < other

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.face + other

    def __str__(self):
        if self._face == 1:
            face_str = 'A'
        elif self._face == 11:
            face_str = 'J'
        elif self._face == 12:
            face_str = 'Q'
        elif self._face == 13:
            face_str = 'K'
        else:
            face_str = str(self._face)
        return f'{self._suite}{face_str}'

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()


class Poker(object):
    """deck of card"""

    def __init__(self):
        self._cards = [Card(suite, face)
                       for suite in '♠♥♣♦'
                       for face in range(1, 14)]
        self._current = 0

    @property
    def cards(self):
        return self._cards

    def shuffle(self):
        """random shuffle"""
        self._current = 0
        random.shuffle(self._cards)

    @property
    def next(self):
        """dealing cards"""
        card = self._cards[self._current]
        self._current += 1
        return card

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self._cards[item]


class Person(object):
    """for both dealer and players"""

    def __init__(self, name, bet):
        self._name = name
        self._cards_on_hand = []
        self._bet = bet
        self._not_bust = True
        self._21 = False

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @property
    def cards_on_hand(self):
        return self._cards_on_hand

    @cards_on_hand.setter
    def cards_on_hand(self, value):
        self._cards_on_hand = value

    def __getitem__(self, a, b):
        return self._cards_on_hand[a:b]

    @property
    def bet(self):
        return self._bet

    @bet.setter
    def bet(self, value):
        self._bet = value

    @property
    def not_bust(self):
        return self._not_bust

    @not_bust.setter
    def not_bust(self, value):
        self._not_bust = value

    @property
    def have21(self):
        return self._21

    @have21.setter
    def have21(self, value):
        self._21 = value

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        return self.bet / other

    def get(self, card):
        """getting cards"""
        self._cards_on_hand.append(card)

    def arrange(self, card_key):
        """arrange the card"""
        self._cards_on_hand.sort(key=card_key)

    def sum_on_hand(self, hand=None):
        total_big = 0
        ace_in = None
        for face in self._cards_on_hand:
            if face > 10:
                face = 10
            if face == 1:
                face = 11
                ace_in = True
            total_big = face + total_big
        if total_big > 21 and ace_in:
            if total_big - 10 < 21:  # take the smaller count
                return total_big - 10
            else:
                self.not_bust = False
                return False
        elif total_big > 21:
            self.not_bust = False
            return False
        else:
            return total_big

    def check_bust(self, hand=None):
        if not self.sum_on_hand(self.cards_on_hand):
            self.not_bust = False
            self.bet = 0
            return False
        elif self.sum_on_hand(self.cards_on_hand) == 21:
            print(f'{self.name} got 21!')
            self.have21 = True
            return True
        else:
            return True

    @property
    def natural_21(self):  # check whether the person got 21 in the beginning
        if self.sum_on_hand(self.cards_on_hand) == 21:
            self.have21 = True
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def clear(self):
        self.cards_on_hand.clear()
        self._not_bust = True
        self.have21 = False


class Player(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, bet=0):
        super().__init__(name, bet)
        self._second_hand = []
        self._insurance = False
        self._option = {"hit": self.hit, "stand": self.stand, "double down": self.double_down}
        self._have_split = False
        self._have_surrender = False
        self.initial_bet = bet
        self._second_not_bust = True
        self.first_not_bust = True
        self.second_bet = 0
        self.second_have21 = False

    @property
    def second_hand(self):
        return self._second_hand

    @second_hand.setter
    def second_hand(self, value):
        self.second_hand = value

    @property
    def insurance(self):
        return self._insurance

    @insurance.setter
    def insurance(self, value):
        self._insurance = value

    @property
    def option(self):
        return self._option

    @option.setter
    def option(self, value):
        self._option = value

    @property
    def second_not_bust(self):
        return self._second_not_bust

    @second_not_bust.setter
    def second_not_bust(self, value):
        self._second_not_bust = value

    @property
    def have_surrender(self):
        return self._have_surrender

    @have_surrender.setter
    def have_surrender(self, value):
        self._have_surrender = value

    @property
    def have_split(self):
        return self._have_split

    @have_split.setter
    def have_split(self, value):
        self._have_split = value

    def sum_on_hand(self, hand=None):
        if hand == self.cards_on_hand:
            total_big = 0
            ace_in = None
            for face in self.cards_on_hand:
                if face > 10:
                    face = 10
                if face == 1:
                    face = 11
                    ace_in = True
                total_big = face + total_big
            if total_big > 21 and ace_in:
                if total_big - 10 <= 21:
                    return total_big - 10
                else:
                    self.not_bust = False
                    return False
            elif total_big > 21:
                self.not_bust = False
                return False
            else:
                return total_big
        else:
            total_big = 0
            ace_in = None
            for face in hand:
                if face > 10:
                    face = 10
                if face == 1:
                    face = 11
                    ace_in = True
                total_big = face + total_big
            if total_big > 21 and ace_in:
                if total_big - 10 <= 21:
                    return total_big - 10
                else:
                    self.second_not_bust = False
                    return False
            elif total_big > 21:
                self.second_not_bust = False
                return False
            else:
                return total_big

    def check_bust(self, hand=None):
        if not self.have_split:
            if not self.sum_on_hand(hand):
                self.first_not_bust = False
                self.bet = 0
                return False
            elif self.sum_on_hand(hand) == 21:
                print(f'{self.name} got 21!')
                self.have21 = True
                return True
            else:
                return True
        else:
            if hand == self.cards_on_hand:
                if not self.sum_on_hand(hand):
                    self.first_not_bust = False
                    self.bet = 0
                    return False
                elif self.sum_on_hand(hand) == 21:
                    print(f'{self.name}\'s first hand got 21!')
                    self.have21 = True
                    return True
                else:
                    return True
            else:
                if not self.sum_on_hand(hand):
                    self._second_not_bust = False
                    self.second_bet = 0
                    return False
                elif self.sum_on_hand(hand) == 21:
                    print(f'{self.name}\'s second hand got 21!')
                    self.second_have21 = True
                    return True
                else:
                    return True

    def hit(self, card, hand):
        hand.append(card.next)
        if self.check_bust(hand) and self.have21:
            print(self)
            return print("action completed\n" + "-" * 20)
        elif self.check_bust(hand):
            pass
        else:
            print(f'{self.name}:\n{hand}\tbet:{self.bet}')
            return print(f'{self.name} bust!', end="\n\n")
        print(self)
        while len(hand) < 5:
            ans = input("do you want to hit once more?(yes|no):")
            if ans == "yes":
                hand.append(card.next)
                if self.check_bust(hand) and self.have21:  # if the player doesn't bust and have 21
                    print(self)
                    return print("action completed\n" + "-" * 20)
                elif self.check_bust(hand):
                    print(self)
                else:  # the player busts
                    print(f'{self.name}:\n{hand}\tbet:{self.bet}')
                    return print(f'{self.name} bust!\n' + "-" * 20)
            elif ans == "no":
                return print("action completed\n" + "-" * 20)
            else:  # second chance for careless mistake in inputting
                print("please enter a valid order, otherwise your decision will be defaulted as no")
                ans01 = {"yes": True, "no": False}.get(str(input("do you want to hit once more?(yes|no):")).lower(),
                                                       False)
                if ans01:
                    hand.append(card.next)
                    if self.check_bust(hand):
                        print(self)
                    else:
                        print(f'{self.name}:\n{hand}\tbet:{self.bet}')
                        return print(f'{self.name} burst!', end="\n")
                else:
                    print(self)
                    return print("action completed\n", "-" * 20)
        else:
            return print("you cannot hit anymore as your total card number in hand reached 5\n" + "-" * 20)

    def stand(self):
        print(self)
        return print("action completed\n" + "-" * 20)

    def double_down(self, card, hand):
        if hand == self.cards_on_hand:
            self.bet *= 2
            hand.append(card.next)
            if self.check_bust(hand):
                print(self)
                return print("action completed\n" + "-" * 20)
            else:
                print(self)
                return print(f'{self.name} bust!\n' + "-" * 20)
        else:
            self.second_bet *= 2
            hand.append(card.next)
            if self.check_bust(hand):
                print(self)
                return print("action completed\n" + "-" * 20)
            else:
                print(self)
                return print(f'{self.name} bust!\n' + "-" * 20)

    def surrender(self):
        self.bet //= 2  # lost half of the player's bet
        self.have_surrender = True
        print(f'{self.name} has surrendered.')
        return print("action completed\n" + "-" * 20)

    def split(self, card):
        self.second_bet = self.bet * 1  # create another bet box
        self._have_split = True
        self.second_hand.append(self.cards_on_hand[1])
        self._cards_on_hand = self.cards_on_hand[0:1]
        print(self)
        self.cards_on_hand.append(card.next)
        self.second_hand.append(card.next)
        if self.have21 and not self.second_have21:
            print(self)
            print("-" * 20)
            print("[second hand]:\n")
            self.choice(card, self.second_hand)
        elif not self.have21 and not self.second_have21:
            print(self)
            print("-" * 20)
            print("[first hand]:\n")
            self.choice(card, self.cards_on_hand)
            print("[second hand]:\n")
            self.choice(card, self.second_hand)
        elif self.have21 and self.second_have21:
            print(self)
            return print("action completed\n" + "-" * 20)
        else:
            print(self)
            print("-" * 20)
            print("[first hand]:\n")
            self.choice(card, self.cards_on_hand)

    def decide_insurance(self):
        print(f'{self.name}, do you want to buy insurance(yes|no):', end="")
        want = input("")
        if want == "yes":
            self.bet *= 1.5
            self.insurance = True
        elif want == "no":
            return
        else:
            print("please enter a valid order, otherwise your decision will be defaulted as no")
            choice01 = {"yes": True, "no": False}.get(str(input("do you want to buy insurance(yes|no):")).lower(),
                                                      False)
            if choice01:
                self.bet *= 1.5
                self.insurance = True
            else:
                return

    def choice(self, card, hand):
        if not self._have_split and hand[0] == hand[1]:
            self.option.update({"split": self.split})
        if self._have_split and "split" in self.option and "surrender" in self.option:
            self.option.pop("split")
            self.option.pop("surrender")
        if (not self._have_split) and len(hand) == 2:
            self.option.update({"surrender": self.surrender})
        print(self)
        print(f'options offered for {self.name}:{list(self.option.keys())}')
        chosen = str(input("please type your decision here:")).lower()
        if chosen == "hit" or chosen == "double down":
            self.option[chosen](card, hand)
        elif chosen == "split" and "split" in self.option:
            self.option[chosen](card)
        elif chosen == "stand" or chosen == "surrender":
            self.option[chosen]()
        else:
            print("\nplease enter a valid order, otherwise your decision will be defaulted as stand")
            print(f'options offered for {self.name}:{list(self.option.keys())}')
            chosen = input("please type your decision here:")
            if chosen == "hit" or chosen == "double down":
                self.option[chosen](card, hand)
            elif chosen == "split" and "split" in self.option:
                self.option[chosen](card)
            else:
                self.option["stand"]()

    def get_result(self, dealer_sum):

        def comp(a, b):  # four situation in comparing
            if a == b:
                return "draw"
            elif a > b and a == 21:
                return "win with 21"
            elif a > b and a != 21:
                return "bigger than host"
            else:
                return "lost"

        if not self._have_split:
            return comp(self.sum_on_hand(self.cards_on_hand), dealer_sum)
        else:
            return f"{comp(self.sum_on_hand(self.cards_on_hand), dealer_sum)}|{comp(self.sum_on_hand(self.second_hand), dealer_sum)}"

    def clear(self):  # restore the default value when starting a new game
        super().clear()
        self.second_hand.clear()
        self._insurance = False
        self._option = {"hit": self.hit, "stand": self.stand, "double down": self.double_down}
        self._have_split = False
        self._have_surrender = False
        self._second_not_bust = True
        self.first_not_bust = True
        self.bet = self.bet + self.second_bet
        self.second_bet = 0
        self.second_have21 = False

    def __repr__(self):
        if len(self.second_hand) > 0:
            if self.first_not_bust and self.second_not_bust:
                return f'{self.name}:\nfirst hand:{self.cards_on_hand} second hand: {self.second_hand}\tfirst bet:{self.bet}\tsecond bet:{self.second_bet}' \
                       f'\t sum of first hand:{self.sum_on_hand(self.cards_on_hand)}\tsum of second hand:{self.sum_on_hand(self.second_hand)}'
            elif not self.first_not_bust and self.second_not_bust:
                return f'{self.name}:\nfirst hand:[bust] second hand: {self.second_hand}\tfirst bet:{self.bet}\tsecond bet:{self.second_bet}' \
                       f'\t sum of second hand:{self.sum_on_hand(self.second_hand)}'
            elif self.first_not_bust and not self.second_not_bust:
                return f'{self.name}:\nfirst hand:{self.cards_on_hand} second hand:[bust]\tfirst bet:{self.bet}\tsecond bet:{self.second_bet}' \
                       f'\t sum of first hand:{self.sum_on_hand(self.cards_on_hand)}'
            else:
                return f'{self.name}:\nfirst hand:[bust] second hand:[bust]\tfirst bet:{self.bet}\tsecond bet:{self.second_bet}'
        elif not self.not_bust:
            return f'{self.name}:\n[bust]\t bet:{self.bet}'
        else:
            return f'{self.name}:\n{self.cards_on_hand}\tbet:{self.bet}\t  sum:{self.sum_on_hand(self.cards_on_hand)}'


class Dealer(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, bet=0):
        super().__init__(name, bet)
        self._blackjack = False
        self.last = False

    @property
    def blackjack(self):
        return self._blackjack

    @blackjack.setter
    def blackjack(self, value):
        self._blackjack = value

    def get(self, card):
        self.cards_on_hand.append(card)

    @property
    def natural_21(self):
        if self.sum_on_hand == 21:
            self.blackjack = True
            return True
        else:
            return False

    @property
    def check_Ace(self):
        check = self.cards_on_hand[0]
        if check.face == 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def initial_secondT(self):
        check01 = self.cards_on_hand[1]
        if check01.face == 10:
            self.blackjack = True
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def clear(self):
        super().clear()
        self.blackjack = False
        self.last = False

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.blackjack or self.last:
            if self.not_bust:
                return f'{self.name}:\n{self.cards_on_hand}\tsum:{self.sum_on_hand()}'
            else:
                return f'{self.name}:\n[bust]\t'
        elif not self.not_bust:
            return f'{self.name}:\n[bust]'
        else:
            return f'{self.name}:\n[{self.cards_on_hand[0]},hidden card*{len(self.cards_on_hand) - 1}]'


# key of arranging the cards in hand
def get_key(card):
    return card.face, card.suite


def blackjack():
    p = Poker()
    p.shuffle()
    players = [Player('player 1', 100), Player('player 2', 100), Player('player 3', 100)]
    host = Dealer("host")
    game = True

    def player_get(time=1):
        for count in range(time):
            for people in players:
                people.get(p.next)

    def player_display():
        for each in players:
            each.arrange(get_key)
            print(each)

    def host_get_display():
        host.get(p.next)
        print(host)

    def all_display(time=1):
        for times in range(time):
            player_get()
            player_display()
            host_get_display()
            print("-" * 20)

    def all_clear():
        for rubbish in players:
            rubbish.not_bust = True
            rubbish.clear()
        host.clear()

    def zero_bet():  # check any player has invalid bet
        for _ in players:
            if _.bet <= 0:
                print(
                    f"{_.name},your bet must at least reach 100,please add your bet,otherwise your bet will be defaulted 100.")

                def inputNumber(message):
                    while True:
                        try:
                            userInput = int(input(message))
                        except ValueError:
                            print("please enter a valid number,otherwise your bet will be will be defaulted 100.")
                            continue
                        else:
                            return userInput

                want_add = inputNumber("how much do you want to add:")
                if want_add > 0 and _.bet + want_add >= 100:
                    _.bet += want_add
                else:
                    print("please enter a valid number,otherwise your bet will be will be defaulted 100.")
                    want_add01 = inputNumber("how much do you want to add:")
                    if want_add01 > 0 and _.bet + want_add01 >= 100:
                        _.bet += want_add01
                    else:
                        _.bet = 100

    def play():
        print("-" * 20)
        all_clear()  # clear the hand
        p.shuffle()  # shuffling cards
        zero_bet()  # check bet
        all_display(2)  # deal the cards to players and host
        have_21 = []
        for anyone in players:  # check who have got 21 and decide the situation
            if anyone.natural_21:
                have_21.append(anyone.name)
                anyone.have21 = True
        nonlocal game
        game = False
        if host.natural_21:  # these parts for anyone who got 21 in the beginning
            have_21.append(host.name)
        if len(have_21) > 1 and host.blackjack:  # draw
            print(f'{",".join(have_21)} have 21.')
            print("Draw")
            print("new game?(yes|no):", end="")
            game = {"yes": True, "no": False}.get(str(input()).lower(), False)
            print()
            return
        elif host.name in have_21:  # host wins
            if host.check_Ace:  # let the players have a chance to win money if the first card of host is Ace
                player_display()
                for everyone in players:
                    everyone.decide_insurance()
                print(host)
                print("Players who bought insurance won 2 times of the insurance!")
                for have in players:
                    if have.insurance:
                        have.bet = have.bet * 5 // 3  # return the insurance and win 2 times of the insurance
                        print(f'{have.name}\'s current bet is {have.bet}:')
                game = {"yes": True, "no": False}.get(str(input("new game?(yes|no)").lower()), False)
                print()  # for clearer display
                return
            else:  # if the first card is T, no chance.
                print(f'{host.name} has 21')
                print(f'{host.name} wins!')
                print(host)
                print("new game?(yes|no):", end="")
                game = {"yes": True, "no": False}.get(str(input()).lower(), False)
                print()
                return
        elif host.name not in have_21 and have_21:  # player(s) win
            print()
            print(f'{",".join(have_21)} has 21')
            print(f'{",".join(have_21)} wins!Profit is 150% of his/her bet')
            for __ in players:
                if __.have21:
                    __.bet *= 2.5
                    print(f'{__.name}\'s current bet is {__.bet}:')
            print("new game?(yes|no):", end="")
            game = {"yes": True, "no": False}.get(str(input()).lower(), False)
            print()
            return
        else:
            pass

        if host.check_Ace:  # if the host gets Ace, the host need to ask whether the players want insurance
            player_display()
            for everyone in players:
                everyone.decide_insurance()
            if host.initial_secondT():
                print(host, end="\n")
                print(host)
                print("Players who bought insurance won 2 times of the insurance!")
                for have in players:
                    if have.insurance:
                        have.bet = have.bet * 5 // 3  # return the insurance and win 2 times of the insurance
                        print(f'{have.name}\'s current bet is {have.bet}:')
                choice = input("new game?(yes|no)")
                game = choice == "yes"
            else:
                print(f"{host.name}did not get a blackjack,the insurance bought is lost,game goes on.")
                print()
                for _ in players:
                    if _.insurance:
                        _.bet = _.initial_bet  # player will lose their insurance and game goes on

        for ask in players:  # ask players' decision
            ask.choice(p, ask.cards_on_hand)

        while True:  # the host will get card until he reach 17
            host.last = True
            if host.sum_on_hand() < 17 and len(host.cards_on_hand) < 5 and host.check_bust():
                print(f"{host.name} is getting...")
                host_get_display()
            elif host.sum_on_hand() >= 17 or not host.check_bust():
                print(f"{host.name} can't get anymore")
                break

        print("-" * 20)
        if not host.not_bust:  # if the host busts
            player_display()
            print(host)
            print(f'{host.name} bust!')
            print("player(s) left with blackjack won profit of 1.5 times of his/her bet,else have 1 times")
            for left in players:
                if not left.have_split:  # for those who didn't split
                    if left.have21:
                        left.bet *= 2.5
                        print(f'{left.name}\'s current bet:{left.bet}')
                    elif left.not_bust:
                        left.bet *= 2
                        print(f'{left.name}\'s current bet:{left.bet}')
                    print("-" * 20)
                else:
                    if left.have21:
                        left.bet *= 2.5
                        print(f'{left.name}\'s current first bet:{left.bet}')
                    elif left.not_bust:
                        left.bet *= 2
                        print(f'{left.name}\'s current first bet:{left.bet}')
                    if left.second_have21:
                        left.second_bet *= 2.5
                        print(f'{left.name}\'s current second bet:{left.second_bet}')
                    elif left.second_not_bust:
                        left.second_bet *= 2
                        print(f'{left.name}\'s current second bet:{left.second_bet}')
                    print("-" * 20)
                print("new game?(yes|no):", end="")
                game = {"yes": True, "no": False}.get(str(input()).lower(), False)
                return

        win_with_21 = []  # four situations if the host didn't bust
        bigger_than_host = []
        lost = []
        draw = []
        result = {"win_with_21": "player(s) left with blackjack won profit of 1.5 times of his/her bet ",
                  "bigger_than_host": "player(s) who win host without 21 won profit of 1 times of his/her bet",
                  "lost": "player(s) who lost host without 21 lost his/her bet",
                  "draw": "player(s) who got a draw have their bet return"}  # description of result

        for winner in players:
            if not winner.have_surrender and not winner.have_split:  # for player who didn't surrender and didn't split
                situation = winner.get_result(host.sum_on_hand())
                if situation == "win with 21":
                    winner.bet *= 2.5
                    win_with_21.append(winner.name)
                elif situation == "bigger than host":
                    winner.bet *= 2
                    bigger_than_host.append(winner.name)
                elif situation == "draw":
                    draw.append(winner.name)
                else:
                    winner.bet = 0
                    lost.append(winner.name)
            elif not winner.have_surrender and winner.have_split:  # for player who have spited and didn't surrender
                situation01 = (winner.get_result(host.sum_on_hand()).split("|"))[0]
                situation02 = (winner.get_result(host.sum_on_hand()).split("|"))[1]
                if situation01 == "win with 21":  # the situation for first hand
                    winner.bet *= 2.5
                    win_with_21.append(f'{winner.name}\'s first hand')
                elif situation01 == "bigger than host":
                    winner.bet *= 2
                    bigger_than_host.append(f'{winner.name}\'s first hand')
                elif situation01 == "draw":
                    draw.append(f'{winner.name}\'s first hand')
                else:
                    winner.bet = 0
                    lost.append(f'{winner.name}\'s first hand')

                if situation02 == "win with 21":  # the situation for second hand
                    winner.second_bet *= 2.5
                    win_with_21.append(f'{winner.name}\'s second hand')
                elif situation02 == "bigger than host":
                    winner.second_bet *= 2
                    bigger_than_host.append(f'{winner.name}\'s second hand')
                elif situation02 == "draw":
                    draw.append(f'{winner.name}\'s second hand')
                else:
                    winner.second_bet = 0
                    lost.append(f'{winner.name}\'s second hand')
            else:
                pass
        print("calculating result...\n" + "-" * 20)  # just for fun
        print(result["win_with_21"] + ":\n" + ",".join(win_with_21))
        print(result["bigger_than_host"] + ":\n" + ",".join(bigger_than_host))
        print(result["lost"] + ":\n" + ",".join(lost))
        print(result["draw"] + ":\n" + ",".join(draw))
        print("-" * 20)
        player_display()
        print(host)
        print("new game?(yes|no):", end="")
        game = {"yes": True, "no": False}.get(str(input()).lower(), False)
        return

    while game:
        play()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    blackjack()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Lookup for faces

This:

```
    if self._face == 1:
        face_str = 'A'
    elif self._face == 11:
        face_str = 'J'
    elif self._face == 12:
        face_str = 'Q'
    elif self._face == 13:
        face_str = 'K'
```

would be made simpler and faster if you were to keep a (static) lookup tuple, something like

```
class Card:  # p.s. don't inherit from object if you're in 3.x
    FACES = (
        None,  # 0 doesn't have a face
        'A',
        *range(2, 11),  # 2 through 10
        *'JQK'
    )

    # ...
    FACES[self._face]
```

### Typo

`suite` is actually `suit`.

### Conflating presentation and logic

This:

```
Card(suite, face)
for suite in '♠♥♣♦'
```

shouldn't require that people outside of `Card` know the special suit characters. Instead, you should make an `enum.Enum` whose values are set to those characters, and pass that.

This could look like:

```
class Suit(Enum):
    SPADE = "♠"
    HEART = "♥"
    CLUB = "♣"
    DIAMOND = "♦"

# ...

        self._cards = [Card(suit, face) for suit in Suit]
```

### Properties

This:

```
@property
def not_bust(self):
    return self._not_bust

@not_bust.setter
def not_bust(self, value):
    self._not_bust = value
```

is somewhat of a Java-ism. It's not buying you anything. You're better off just making `not_bust` a "public" member variable and doing away with the properties (private-by-underscore is more of a suggestion and is not enforced, anyway).

### Return-from-print

This:

```
                return print("action completed\n" + "-" * 20)
```

does not do what you think it does. `print` does not return anything, so you are always returning `None`, which is equivalent to:

```
print("action completed\n" + "-" * 20)
return
```

### Input parsing

This:

```
            ans01 = {"yes": True, "no": False}.get(str(input("do you want to hit once more?(yes|no):")).lower(),
                                                   False)
```

is more complicated than it needs to be, and is equivalent to

```
hit_again = input('do you want to hit once more?').lower() == 'yes'
```

Also note that you do not need to explicitly convert the return of `input` to a string, since it is already; and you need a better variable name.

### Set membership

```
    elif chosen == "stand" or chosen == "surrender":
```

can be

```
elif chosen in {'stand', 'surrender'}:
```

### Booleans and early-return

```
        if a == b:
            return "draw"
        elif a > b and a == 21:
            return "win with 21"
        elif a > b and a != 21:
            return "bigger than host"
        else:
            return "lost"
```

can be

```
if a == b:
    return 'draw'
if a < b:
    return 'lost'
if a == 21:
    return 'win with 21'
return 'bigger than host'
```

Also, this:

```
    if check.face == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

can be

```
return check.face == 1
```

### Underscore variables

```
    for _ in players:
        if _.bet <= 0:
```

should not use an underscore. Underscores, by convention, mean "I won't use this variable", but you do anyway. So just `for player in players`.

Comment: Thank you! I would try to modify my code!

Comment: Could you explain the part **conflating representation and logic*** once more please? I don't understand how it actually looks like.  Do you mean this? `class Suit(Enum):
    Spade = "♠"
    Heart = "♥"
    Club = "♣"
    Diamond = "♦"`

Comment: Yes; edited. Enum constants are capitalized.